# Inactive cursor with my touchpad

Tags: touchpad, cursor

Cursor is inactive with touchpad on my Ubuntu 14.40. I can see the cursor and it's active with the mouse, but it's inactive when I use the touchpad.

I ran the command synclient touchpadOff=0

Even when after restarting the machine, the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, I did try synclient command but the problem persists

Comment: is it after boot or only after the computer went to sleep?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact `synclient` command you ran.

Comment: I have edited my question. The problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling enabling it through this command:

```
synclient touchpadOff=0
```